# Check if dict gets consecutive incremental counters

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key, counter

I constructed the following dictionary, which obtains counters starting from a `for-loop`. The `for-loop` does something like this:

```
for period in range(number_periods):

  if value > mean_value: 

    dict[key] += 1 ​
```

From this, I get the following dictionary:

```
dict = {(1, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (3, 3): 3}
```

Now I want to figure out that if a key in the dictionary gets a counter in, e.g. three consecutive periods of the `for-loop` (i.e. `k=3`), I want to identify and store these keys in a new dictionary separately.

Hence, if the following happens, I want to create a new dictionary or print the specific key in which the counters increased consecutively.

```
period = 1: dict = {(1, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (3, 3): 0}
period = 2: dict = {(1, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (3, 3): 1}
period = 3: dict = {(1, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (3, 3): 2}
period = 4: dict = {(1, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (3, 3): 3}

new_dict = {(3, 3): 1}
```

That is, the `new_dict` represents the keys in which this consecutive increment has occurred (which happened exactly once if `k=3` for the given example.

The `new_dict` itself should feature a counting feature, i.e. whenever the counter in `dict` increases three consecutive times, a counter in `new_dict` should increase by `1`. If this happens another time, the `new_dict`should be adjusted again:

```
new_dict = {(3, 3): 2}
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: What other possible values might you want to see in `new_dict`? You show one example with a single key and a value: `1`.

Comment: Perhaps the best would be to implement another counting feature, i.e. whenever the counter in `new_dict` increases (i.e. for three periods the counter in `dict` increased by `1`), then again the counter in `new_dict` should be increased by `1` and this for all keys.

Comment: Do you mean that the value in `new_dict` should be the value in `dict` (btw please use another name) divided by 3?

Comment: The `new_dict` should simply count the instances when three consecutive counters have occurred in the `dict` (e.g. if (3,3) gets a counter in period 1, 2, and 3, then the `new_dict` should count this as `1`). Please excuse the bad naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you might want this to happen is to check when you increment a value in `dict`:

```py
for period in range(number_periods):
    if value > mean_value: 
        dict[key] += 1 ​
        v = dict[key]
        v3 = v//3
        if v3 > 0:
            new_dict[key] = v3
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is exactly what I was looking for.